# My listview is not updating when the observable list updates

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm working on a basic app and the listview is not updating when I change it, the following is the base class and the observable list

```
    public class Menu
{
    public Menu(string itemname, string itemdescrip, string cost, string allergens)
    {
        ItemName = itemname;
        ItemDescription = itemdescrip;
        ItemCost = cost;
        ItemAmount = 0;
        ItemAllergens = allergens;
    }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemCost { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public int ItemAmount { get; set; }
    public string ItemAllergens { get; set; }

}

public class MenuList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<Menu> _items;

    public ObservableCollection<Menu> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public MenuList(List<Menu> itemList)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Menu>();
        foreach (Menu itm in itemList)
        {
            Items.Add(itm);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the listviewpage class

```
public List<Menu> allItems;
    MenuList items;

    public ListViewPage1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        allItems = new List<Menu>{inserted data};
        items = new MenuList(allItems);
        MyListView.ItemsSource = items.Items;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_Pos(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Increase Amount
        var item = (Xamarin.Forms.Button)sender;
        items.Items[1].ItemAmount += 1;
    }
```

And then finally the xaml of the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>                          
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.ListViewPage1">
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <Grid x:Name="Item">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label WidthRequest="15" Text="{Binding ItemName}" Margin="1,1,1,1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemCost}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="-" FontSize="Large" Clicked="Button_Clicked_Neg" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemAmount}"></Button>
                        <Label x:Name="lblAmount" Text="{Binding ItemAmount}" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                        <Button Grid.Column="4" Text="+" FontSize="Large" Clicked="Button_Clicked_Pos" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemAmount}"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Any help would be much appriciated. I've been struggling with this for a while, the list updates, I've tested that, but the command paramater does not change at all.

Is it better to have the observable list or should I rather look for a way to reset the page?

Comment: an ObservableCollection only raises events when items are added or removed from the collection.  It does not do anything when a property of an item changes.  For that, each item in the list (ie, Menu) needs to implement INPC

Comment: Thanks @Jason that worked.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to assign the BindingContext

```
public ListViewPage1()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    allItems = new List<Menu>{inserted data};
    items = new MenuList(allItems);
   // MyListView.ItemsSource = items.Items;
this.BindingContext =items ;
}
```